# Me devuelve dos objetos de la lista a nulos aún haciendo JOIN

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Estoy tratando de obtener una lista de roles a partir de una lista de ids de los mismos

Metodo que llama a la consulta
[image: Llamada al método]

Consulta que devuelve el objeto RusuarioRol
[image: Consulta unión de dos tablas]

Objeto RusuarioRol, el cual tiene asociado RrolCode, por el cual he hecho LEFT JOIN y, aunque RusuarioRol esté a nulo, solo deberían estar a nulos los campos id y Rusuario, el campo RrolCode debería ir informado al estar asociado a la otra tabla
[image: Objeto que devuelve, el cual está unido a otro objeto]

Relación de las tablas, mediante la cual RROL_CODE -> RrolCode y RUSUARIO_ROL -> RusuarioRol, están unidas
[image: Relación de las tablas]

El caso es que cuando ejecuto el servicio, y llama a este método, me devuelve la lista con todos los objetos, pero dos de ellos, los cuales no están en la tabla RUSUARIO_ROL, me vienen completamente a nulos los dos, los demás si que me vienen informados. Sin embargo, al ejecutar esta misma consulta en base de de datos, si me devuelve información

Al depurar, dos objetos devueltos a nulo
[image: Los dos obetos que me devuelve a nulo]

Sin embargo, al realizar esta misma consulta, devuelve los dos registros
que en la depuración del programa me devuelve a nulos completamente, son los dos que están abajo del todo
[image: Ejecución de la consulta con devolución de datos]

¿Alguna idea sobre lo que ocurre, por favor?